# OpenLayers: the rendering of a COG geotiff works in Chrome and not in Firefox

Tags: openlayers

I have built [this sample page](https://codesandbox.io/s/cog-notgeo-forked-79opgx?file=/main.js) in which I render a COG Geotiff.
It works properly in Chrome and not in Firefox.

I read the errors in console, but I don't understand what the problem is.

I have also built it using `npm run build`, and published it here:
https://andybandy.it/progetti/tmp/cog-nogeo/

And it's the same: I view it in Chrome and not in Firefox

```js
import GeoTIFF from "ol/source/GeoTIFF.js";
import Map from "ol/Map.js";
import TileLayer from "ol/layer/WebGLTile.js";
import Projection from "ol/proj/Projection.js";
import View from "ol/View.js";
import { getCenter } from "ol/extent.js";

const extent = [23093, -19213, 45245, 2973];

const projection = new Projection({
  code: "custom",
  units: "pixels",
  extent: extent
});

const map = new Map({
  target: "map",
  layers: [
    new TileLayer({
      source: new GeoTIFF({
        convertToRGB: true,
        sources: [
          {
            url: "https://andy-aws.s3.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com/10_1155.tif"
          }
        ]
      })
    })
  ],
  view: new View({
    projection: projection,
    center: getCenter(extent),
    extent: extent,
    zoom: 1
  })
});
```

Comment: The request for the file returns 403 Forbidden status if loaded directly by the source, but does work if loaded as a blob as in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/cog-blob.html  Presumably a difference in browser security settings?

Comment: @Mike but in this example firefox loads it without passing from blob https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/cog.html

Comment: @Mike please look also at this example that I have built, based on that code and in which the tif is in the same server. I have the same problem and I do not have 403 error in firefox. But it does not work in firefox https://andybandy.it/progetti/tmp/cog-nogeo/

Comment: I think that is being reported when using CodeSandbox because it is cross origin.  As noted in https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/13703#issuecomment-1136082940 there is a problem with Firefox and even fetching then using an object url as in https://codesandbox.io/s/cog-notgeo-forked-xzpfxp?file=/main.js does not work.

Comment: @Mike thank you for the reporting the issue 13703. That issue is solved, but I'm still not able to render the geotiff in firefox  https://andybandy.it/progetti/tmp/cog-nogeo/

Comment: If it is a Firefox issue, the only workaround is to use the GeoTIFF blob option https://codesandbox.io/s/cog-notgeo-forked-v5d6pw?file=/main.js

Comment: @Mike in this workaround you  have the full download of the entire tif, does not use the COG "HTTP GET range requests"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254023/discussion-between-aborruso-and-mike).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have set wrong CORS parameter in S3.

I have set in this way and it works

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "Authorization",
            "Content-Range",
            "Accept",
            "Content-Type",
            "Origin",
            "Range"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [
            "Content-Range",
            "Content-Length",
            "ETag"
        ],
        "MaxAgeSeconds": 3000
    }
]
```